# Python loop query

Tags: python

I have the following loop:

```
for n in range (len(xvalues)):
    if ((250 < yvalues[n]) and (250 < yvalues[n+1]) and (250 < yvalues[n+2])and (250 < yvalues[n+3]) and (250 < yvalues[n+4]) and (250 < yvalues[n+5])):
        edge1 = xvalues[n]
    else:
        break
```

I want my loop to only give me the corresponding x-value when the y-values are below a threshold of ~250 for a sustained period. Therefore it'll ignore the first dip in y values and pick up the second. Also, I want any further increase in y values in the graphs ignored. Once it has has a valid value, I want it to stop.

At the moment, this loop ignores the any small dip below the threshold but it doesn't stop overwriting the edge1 after the if statement has been fulfilled.

Comment: Please post at least a sample of `yvalues` and `xvalues` and the expected result for this sample.

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand what you meant. Perhaps you should provide a small example.

Comment: by _y-values are below a threshold of ~250 for a sustained period_ i think what you mean is yvalues < 250 but your code says otherwise

Comment: Sorry. X-values go from 0 to around 350. Y -values are pixel values of a patient, starting at the centre of the patient and moving outwards, towards the edge of the body. There can be a bit of equipment outside the patient, but still in the graph, but it register some pixel values.

Comment: Can you give input and your expected output

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish The input is pixel data from a CT slice and the output is a depth in cm. I am trying to work out the distance from the centre of the patient (defined as 0,0) to the edge of their body.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the first `yvalue` among a continuous range of `yvalues < 250`, try this out:

```
for n in range (len(xvalues)):
    if ((250 > yvalues[n]) and (250 > yvalues[n+1]) and (250 > yvalues[n+2])and (250 > yvalues[n+3]) and (250 > yvalues[n+4]) and (250 > yvalues[n+5])):
        edge1 = xvalues[n]
        break
```

If you put `break` in else, even after getting the first value, loop will continue executing. Thus it won't give the `edge1` correctly but instead it might overwrite `edge1`.

OR if you want to have the same `if` condition (yvalues > 250):

```
for n in range (len(xvalues)):
    if ((250 < yvalues[n]) and (250 < yvalues[n+1]) and (250 < yvalues[n+2])and (250 < yvalues[n+3]) and (250 < yvalues[n+4]) and (250 < yvalues[n+5])):
        edge1 = xvalues[n]
        break
```

Comment: I've tried this but now the thresholding part of the if statement doesn't seem to work. It does stop the edge1 from being overwritten however.

Comment: But I want yvalues < 250 not    > 250 ?

Comment: so under what condition you want the edge1 to be overwritten and when not. Also for loop will stop executing once the sudden and sustained increase in yvalues is observed (in 2nd code) or if sudden and sustained decrease in yvalues is oberseved (in 1st code)

Comment: to have `yvalues < 250` see the upper part.

Comment: With the if statement, I want it to provide an xvalue for edge only when there is a sustained decrease in yvalues. It therefore shouldn't give me any value for edge where there isn't a sustained decrease, but it doesn't at the moment and I don't know why.